# How to create a SQL Server replication using DB backup?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am trying to build a DB replication using MSSQL 2005.  Both publisher and subscriber are SQL Server database.  I know I can create subsriber database from the snapshop of publisher.  However, snapshot agent will put the share lock on publisher DB, which is a production database.  Is there any way I can build a replication and initialize subscriber db from restoring a DB backup instead of running snapshot agent?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can.  Here are some things to be aware of:

- You can use profiler to see the scripts that are running at any given time (use it while performing a backup and a restore)
- If you are using a restore to copy a database, once its finished, any users that were tied to the backed up database will have to be recreated.

Comment: Thanks, if there any online document for my reference?

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/02/25/sql-server-restore-database-backup-using-sql-script-t-sql/